# Using List in C# printing class name

Tags: c#, list, object

I'm new to C# coming from C++

I'm currently building a cigarette inventory management system, and I'm creating a separate List to store different brands.

When I add a Cigarette object which carries a title and a MaxInventory to the list, and I go to print it out my output is the project.className

How can I have the program print to console the actual data stored within the list. I need to see a report of the brand and amount of cigarettes currently in the list.

```
        Cigarette marbLight = new Cigarette("Light", 6);
        Cigarette marbRed = new Cigarette("Red", 6);

        List<Cigarette> marlboro = new List<Cigarette>()
        {
           marbLight, marbRed
        };

        marlboro.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

The output:

```
        InventoryManagement.Cigarette

        InventoryManagement.Cigarette
```

Desired output would be the contents of marbLight and marbRed

Thanks in advance!

Comment: override the `ToString()` method within your `Cigarette` class.

Comment: @Aominè Thanks for that worked great!

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine` will call `ToString` on what is passed into it. You can override it in your `Cigarette` class.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return // whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: Coming from C++ I wasn't aware of this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the other person said, you would have to override the `ToString` method in your Cigarette class. An alternative syntax for it is

```
// and your other variables you want to show
public override string ToString() => String.Format("Cigarette contents: {0}", contents);
```

Comment: Used your provided code worked perfect, thanks. Cleared up a whole lot.